# Facebook signup not displaying message properly if user has already been registered

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, facebook

The developer who made it is claiming that this is clearly because of an old PHP version in use. My current PHP version on my server is 5.2.17. I have two options to upgrade it and they are PHP 5.4.45 and 5.6.30. We have already tried to upgrade to 5.4.45 and the whole website went down which probably has something to deal with mysqli or because of deprecated functions or something which apparently nobody on internet can give you an answer to but this is another story. With my current PHP version a person can register with facebook but if he has already registered with this account the code is supposed to execute here

```
    if(mysql_num_rows($prev_query)>0){

    $fbMSG="</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>";
    $fbMSG.="<span class='red'><img alt='Not done icon'   src='website_images/not_done.png' width='14px' height='14px'>";
    $fbMSG.="You are already registered with this email id";
    $fbMSG.="</span>";      
    $_SESSION['FBMSG'] = $fbMSG;

}
```

Instead in the case mentioned above the page opens and displays "500 Internal server error" or now after a few changes  "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...". This developer is working for a company and when he installed the code on their servers where the PHP version is 5.4.45 it is working just the way it is expected. My question is is there a way to make it work on the PHP version I am on or do I really need to upgrade (the scary part where the website goes down). I can give complete code of all facebook code if needed but it is too much to add it in the question.

Comment: Are you able to replicate the site to a VM to test the upgrade and monitor the /var/log/httpd/error_log (or where it stores the log) and see where the site breaks? I had this issue with a site i worked on so i left production alone while figuring out the issues on a Dev server. now the site is upgrade and functioning.

Comment: Not really to be honest and the trouble is my localhost is running with way higher PHP version and it shows no issues but the thing is this is a delicate case and you can not really test it in real time unless it is online and actually register a user with it and then try to register again with the same fb account.

Comment: The code snippet you have shown has nothing to do with Facebook. And if you lack any of the basic skills required to properly analyze such a problem and have no one else in your company able to do it - then I’d suggest you go hire someone to fix this for you.

Comment: If you lack of basic English skills CBroe I would suggest you hire an English teacher to explain to you the sentence above saying "I can give complete code of all facebook code if needed but it is too much to add it in the question." What a shame for all the reputation you have.